# Render JSON in controller action

Tags: grails, controller, json-view

I have a Grails 3.3.8 app with

```
  compile 'org.grails.plugins:views-json'
  compile 'org.grails.plugins:views-json-templates'
```

and a json view under `views/partner/_companion.gson`:

```
import io.my.domain.Companion

model {
  Companion companion
}
json {
  id companion.id
  name companion.name
  description companion.description
}
```

Now I want to render my object to json inside the controller action:

```
class PartnerController {
  def action() {
    Companion o = Companion.get(...)
    log.info render( view:"/partner/_companion", model:[ companion:o ] )
    log.info render( view:"_companion", model:[ companion:o ] )
    log.info render( template:"companion", model:[ companion:o ] )
    log.info render( template:"companion", model:o )
  }
}
```

All of those calla output `null`s.

What is the propper way of rendering?

Comment: You are invoking the `render` method at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v3.3.8/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/grails/artefact/controller/support/ResponseRenderer.groovy#L216.  That has a `void` return type which is why your output is showing `null`.  That method doesn't return a value.  It renders the template to the response.

Comment: `g.render()` wouldn't also work without TagLib plugin, would it?

Comment: That is right.  Even with `g.render()` several of the approaches you show in your code sample wouldn't work.  `view:"/partner/_companion"`, `view:"_companion"` and `model:o` are each invalid.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I think they would work, as I copied them from the working controller with web-profile. Anyway, do you have some lib in mind similar to `json-view` plugin but able to work outside Grails?

Comment: "Anyway, do you have some lib in mind similar to json-view plugin but able to work outside Grails?" - It depends.  Would it be a JVM app?

Comment: yes, JVM like Micronaut or Vert.x